# How to implement Property Change Notification

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In MVVM how should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface: in a ViewModel class or in a Model class? How to handle model's property changed event if INotifyPropertyChanged interface has been implemented in a ViewModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you **always** implement it in your View Model, because that interface is used by the framework to update the UI when you updated data in the view model.

You *can* implement it in the Model, but it is by no means required. If the Model is changing out from under you, you could, and likely should, easily raise your own (semantically clearer) events that the View Model listens to in order to update its data.

The actual implementation should look like this ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quality answer - as stated, I would typically go with the model raising events where values change outside the control of the view model. Notify in models feels like muddy mvvm to me, plus I prefer them to be domain based and reusable in other contexts.